# jQuery Multisortable with CustomScrollBar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-multisortable

I am using the mulisortable jquery plugin (github.com/shvetsgroup/jquery.multisortable) along with mcustomscrollbar plugin (manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller), and I am having trouble displaying the dragged items "overtop" of the customscrollbar containers.

As an example, I have 4 separate containers that utilize the custom scrollbar, and inside each of these containers I have various lists that are connected by the multisortable plugin. I am able to drag selected items from a list in one container to a list in another container, however since the custom scrollbar adds `overflow:hidden` to its container, the dragged items go "behind" the lists/containers.

My question is: how do I make the dragged items appear in front of the containers

Things I've Tried:

- I have removed the `overflow:hidden` properties from the scrollbar, which does what I want, but then when scrolling, the scrolled content appears outside of the container, which is not good.
- I have tried using the `helper:"clone"` setting in the multisortable options, but this seems to only clone one item (instead of multiple) and my originating list css does unexpected things.
- I have also tried setting the z-index on those items which are selected, however this also doesn't seem to help.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ML49V/12/
If anyone has come across this before and has any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), where you can reference external Js libs, and have a live example of your problem.

Comment: I have edited my post to include the jsfiddle

Comment: All of your external files are 404'ing

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to work in IE using the fiddle. However it does work for me in Chrome.

Comment: Oh wait. They aren't working in Chrome now either. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: The path to the files must have changed. It should be working from Chrome now (I edited the link). IE still does not work right... but that is another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some searching I found the answer. If you add the lines below to the mulitsortable options, it works as intended.

The working jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ML49V/13/

```
stop: function (e, ui) {
    var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');
    ui.item.after(elements).remove();
},
helper: function (e, item) {
    if (!item.hasClass("selected")) {
        item.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    }
    var elements = item.parent().children(".selected").clone();
    item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings(".selected").remove();
    var helper = $('<li/>').css('list-style', 'none');
    helper.height('auto');
    return helper.append(elements);
},
```